# I can't vote on comments even after 5 seconds have passed

Tags: bug, status-declined, comment-voting

If you try to vote on two different comments within 5 seconds of each other, it shows the error message:

> You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds.

So I checked to see if this was actually the true time, and to my horror, **it still shows this message even after 5.2 seconds have passed**!

I tested it by running this Javascript code in my browser's console

```
$(".comment-up")[0].id = "first";
$(".comment-up")[1].id = "second";
$("#first").click();
var t = new Date();
var snd = $("#second");
setTimeout(function() {
    var ivl = setInterval(function() {
        nt = new Date();
        console.log(nt - t);
        snd.click();
        if (nt - t > 6000) {
            console.log("end");
            clearInterval(ivl);
        }
    }, 50);
}, 100);
```

And then I ran this test over several threads of comments, and viewed the console logs. The outputs all looked basically like this

```
...
LOG: 4925 
LOG: 4991 
LOG: 5053 
LOG: 5092 
LOG: 5127 
LOG: 5186 
LOG: 5231 
LOG: 5275 
LOG: 5337 
LOG: 7880 
LOG: end
```

This log clearly indicates that even when the comment vote button was clicked **5275 milliseconds** after the first one, it still showed the 5 second error message.

Comment: And it isn't April fools for almost another year.

Comment: @Oded But this isn't about April Fools; it's actually true, the system actually won't let you vote on comments even after more than 5 seconds have passed.

Comment: Oh my god. Please don't tell me this is true? The horror, the HORROR.

Comment: Yes, but concentrating on the 275 ms as an actual problem reads like a joke to me. Really? This is an issue for you? Can't wait for an extra second?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Network latency is probably to blame.  The [code is pretty straight-forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318059/3).